# How would I build Rest + EJB using Weblogic?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic, ejb

I have a need to build 1 restful web service using weblogic. This web service will have parameters to select a what data the service should return. Like 'customer', or 'product'.

Now I want to deploy the 'customer' and 'product' code as a separate deployable applications, so that I can add or remove new code without redeploying all the code each time there is a change.

So I want one generic webservice to call this business logic.

My question is, what is the best way to structure this? Can I deploy separate EJBs for my business logic and have the web service invoke the EJBs based on the passed parameters?

Or should I have the business components as a shared library and call them that way? I am looking for a way to get the best performance.

I will have about 20 different business modules written by other programers. Like I said I don't want all the modules in the same EAR or WAR file. They need to be separately deployable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic 10.3.4 includes new Java EE6 API support including JAX-RS 1.1 with Jersey.  We recently did a webcast on this functionality and Webcast #4 covers JAX-RS.  Here's the link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/learnmore/weblogic-javaee6-webcasts-358613.html  There is also an example application on this called Oracle Parcel Service and you can download the code here: https://www.samplecode.oracle.com/sf/projects/oracle-parcel-svc/.

If you use JAXB you can marshall from JSON and XML into the same Java object.  The challenge here is that the JAXB generated classes are not serializeable by default so if you wanted to access a remote EJB from the JAX-RS service then you would have a problem.

Since you can't have the modules in the same EAR, there is another option.  You could possibly use Java EE shared libraries.  Then you could deploy your EJB's as a Java EE Shared library and reference that library in your REST client.  Here is an example:

In your EJB module, include something like the following in your manifest:

```
Extension-Name: ops-util
Implementation-Title: OPS 2.0 Utils Library EXAMPLE_ONLY
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.oracle
Implementation-Version: 2.0.1
Specification-Title: Oracle Parcel Service 2.0 Utils Library
Specification-Vendor: Oracle
Specification-Version: 2.0
```

Then reference the shared library in weblogic.xml (WAR) or weblogic-application.xml (EAR):

```
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
  <!-- server-version: 10.3 -->
<wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-name>ops-util</wls:library-name>
  <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
  <wls:implementation-version>2.0.1</wls:implementation-version>
  <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Jax-rs. The downside is that by company policy any code that is redeployed to production must be retested even if it was not changed (accidents do happen). So I want to only deploy the new or changed business functions without deploying the entire application.

Comment: Interesting approach, I understand why they would do it but it clearly over-complicates your job.  You can use 'remote' EJB invocation from your JAX-RS app (even though it is deployed on the same container).  Just create an InitialContext with no parameters and you can look up your EJB:

Comment: I was able to deploy an ejb separately from the jax-rs application and get it to work with the remote interface. since the are both running in the same jvm is there a way to get the local interface to work?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure.  I believe the local interface is for use between classes or modules in the same application deployment.  Furthermore, you would have to have your REST module (presumably WAR) and your EJB module (JAR) deployed in an ear file, which violates the requirement of deploying them separately.

Comment: alternatively, you could create a straight-through REST interface for your EJB and deploy it WITH your EJB and then call the EJB through the REST interface from your other REST deployment(s).  Less than ideal, but the proper way to do it is package it your REST and EJB's in an EAR.